# C# Xml Serialization big purpose?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I was just wondering about XML Serialization. If i understand correctly, the main reason for using it is that it lets you transport your object data more easily, am I right? Also, i tried serializing data using a constructor but it says that that you can only serialize data that are "parameterless". The thing is I like constructors because it allows me to have for example a Player class, and adding a new player with all properties is much more productive than having to set all properties one by one. 
So the big question here is, what's the BIG purpose of XML serialization, what are the ways to use it? the way I see it is that it adds another level of complexity to my code, because i now need a class to serialize my data. Can someone shed some light?!

Comment: you no need to create new class to serialize your object. Try to use standard XMLSerializer. Should be enough for most of your tasks. "only serialize data that are "parameterless"" - just add parameterless constructor to your class.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well i like to have different classes for different tasks so that I can only call the class when needed! But thanks for the link, that was helpful :)

Comment: you may create as many classes as you want. XMLSerialiser just convert your class to XML and back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the overall purpose of serialization, strictly speaking, serialization (note that I said "serialization," *not* "XML Serialization" - more on that in a second) doesn't just make transporting objects *easier*, it's the *only* way you could transport an object.

As indicated in Pablo Santa Cruz's answer, XML is one of many ways you can serialize data. If you're going to save or send data somewhere, by definition you must first have some way to represent it. Serialization basically means that you represent your object state in some specified format. Deserialization is the opposite - given some representation of an object state, reconstruct what the original object state was.

In that sense, XML serialization, saving an object state to a database somehow, saving it as JSON, saving it in some binary format, and saving in some XML format are all examples of serialization (because you're representing the object state in a pre-defined format for later use).

While any defined format can technically be serialization, there are several standard ways of doing that. XML and JSON are by far the most common formats because they're standardized, easy to parse, easy to constrain (e.g. with XML Schema), are widely supported by libraries, can be relatively human-readable (which makes debugging easier), and they're widely used.

In case the last point sounds a little odd (they're widely used because they're widely used), standards by their very nature tend to have a strong network effect. In other words, the more people adapt them the more useful they are; for example, it's only useful to have email if you can actually use it to contact other people - it wouldn't be even slightly useful to have email if you were the only one using it.

A lot of standards and technologies will win out over competitors more because they have more early adapters than because they're necessarily technically superior. For example, even if someone could clearly prove that OS X is a "better" operating system than Windows, it wouldn't matter because there's vastly more software developed for Windows and it would be prohibitively expensive for people to try to switch to OS X. (You could make a similar argument for Token Ring vs. Ethernet).

Comment: This was most helpful, thank you for taking the time to give a detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is for storing object representation somehow (on a disk file, on the wire {network transportation}, on a HTTP session, on a database). XML Serialization is just one type of serialization.

The reason you need a parameter-less constructor to support serialization, is that the AUTO DESERIALIZER needs to create an EMPTY (with no o little data) class before start populating it with the corresponding data.

You don't need to use ONE WAY or THE OTHER, because you can have a class with multiple constructor (the parameter-less one will be used on deserialization, and you can use the other one wherever you need in your code).

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, in the context of game making, if you want to have a saved game file, you're going to use XML to serialize the data and deserialize it when you load a saved file, right?